# CSS - li elements get wrong width

Tags: html, css

I have a side menu on a website. It's inside a floated container named `#left_menu`, which contains the `ul` with `li` elements.

The problem is, I would like the `li` elements to have their own generated width instead of inheriting it from `#left_menu`, which they seem to do.

They have to be `text-align`ed to the right and only as wide as they need to be.

**HTML**

```
<div class="left_menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Derp</li>
        <li>Derp</li>
        <li>Derp</li>
        <li>Derp</li>                   
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left_menu{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.left_menu > ul li{
    color: #4c4c4c;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}
.left_menu li:hover{
    color: white;
    background-color: #0072ff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mUP7n/)

Comment: Your title says height but your question says width. Which one is it?

Comment: Width! Sorry, editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Float left and then clear left and you should get what (I think) you're looking for:

```
.left_menu > ul li{
    color: #4c4c4c;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/mUP7n/1/)

Or `float:right` and `clear:right`, depending on which side you are looking to align the buttons.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/mUP7n/5/)

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I'll test it out on the site tomorrow morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just float your `ul` left:

```
.left_menu > ul{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mUP7n/4/